# Using Entity Framework in Visual Studio Team Services Project Source Control

Tags: entity-framework, version-control, visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-devops

i'm using Visual Studio Team Services with another member of the project.
We want to use Entity Framework on our Visual Studio Team Services project, so i created our project and installed Entity Framework through Nuget Package Manager and "Checked-In" to commit the files into TFVC Source Control.

Everything works fine in my machine, but when my colleague "checks-out" the project files he is not able to use the entity Framework. His Entity Framework references are shown with a yellow warning (see red box).

Here's a print-screen of his Visual Studio.
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2013/08/31/are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference-why-yes-i-am-so-kind-of-you-to-ask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason is that you haven't enabled "Allow Nuget to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" from Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager and that the Entity Framework package hasn't been checked in.

Note that by default, Nuget adds the packages to TFS when you install a new package, but if you have TFS configured to ignore dll files, your colleague will see the EntityFramework folder in the Packges folder, but it won't contain the dlls. Check if this is the case and from your machine, go to Source Control Explorer, Packages folder, click Add files and select all the missing dlls.

My preferred option though is to not check in the packages ni source control and let VS restore them at build time, with the options I mentioned in the beginning. With this you avoid these type of issues and also having to clean up the old packages that accumulate over time in source control.

You can find detailed instructions on how to do that, but basically you have to set disableSourceControlIntegration = true in the Nuget.Config file and ignore the Packages folder in the .tfignore file.

Comment: Hi Francesc,
we both had those two options checked  "Allow Nuget to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio"), but my colleague didn't had the dlls files. After adding the three folders (libs, content and tools) and their content to the source control my colleague was finally able run the project. Thank you very much for your help! :)